# index locator in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I need the index of the first open parentheses and last closing parentheses...without using any loop..

example :

```
string='a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q'
```

Comment: `string[1:20]` should do it.

Comment: i only need the index of two parentheses..the first and last...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.find` and `str.rfind` to find the indices of the two characters. Using `str.rfind` its simpler to find the last character and avoids the possibility of out by one errors other approaches may be susceptible to. There is also a `str.rindex` which works a similar way.

Whether you prefer using `str.find`/`str.rfind` or `str.index`/`str.rindex` is a matter of preference on how you wish to handle the absence of the `first`/`last` strings. If you want an exception use `index` if you want a -1 in the returned tuple use `find` .

```
def find_first_last(s, first='(', last=')'):
    return s.find(first), s.rfind(last)

print(find_first_last('a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q'))
# couple of error cases
print(find_first_last('a(bcdefghijkl(mnopq'))
print(find_first_last('abcdefghijklmno)p)q'))
print(find_first_last('abcdefghijklmnopq'))
print(find_first_last('abcdefgh)(ijklmnopq'))
```

output

```
(1, 19) <- all good
(1, -1)
(-1, 17)
(-1, -1)
(9, 8) <- backwards
```

Answer (score 2):

This function finds the indices of the first opening and final closing parentheses:

```
def find_first_last(string, first='(', last=')'):
    return (
        string.index(first),
        len(string) - string[::-1].index(last)
    )

print(find_first_last('a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q'))
# (1, 20)
```

It does so by using the [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) string method, which returns the *lowest* index of a character in a string. For the closing parenthesis it reverses the string to find the last occurrence of that character.

Comment: Clever..Thanks a lot

Comment: what are the first and last for? u changed the function

Comment: I just generalised it so you can look for any characters, not just `(` and `)`. I've also added default arguments so it still works as before by default.

Comment: gotcha...it worked like a charm...thanks again...also add minus 1 ,returns 20  instead of 19